# Tensorflow placeholder from function

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to do something like this:

```
def f():
    place = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
    return 2 * place

y = f()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    a = sess.run(y, feed_dict={ place: 5 })
```

Of course, placeholder place is not visible outside.

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-88-8b3c17d16dce> in <module>()
      1 with tf.Session() as sess:
----> 2     a = sess.run(y, feed_dict={ place: 5 })

NameError: name 'place' is not defined
```

And, I can solve this, in this way:

```
def f():
    global place
    place = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
    return 2 * place
```

But, does anyone have better solution for this. How to create placeholder inside function and feed value to it outside, when function is called and its return value passed as operator to run function as in example above.

Answer (score 3):

You can access the placeholder by its name:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def f():
    place = tf.placeholder(tf.int32,name='place')
    return 2 * place

y = f()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    place = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('place:0')
    a = sess.run(y, feed_dict={ place: 5 })
```

### Explanation

Whenever you define a placeholder (or any other TensorFlow tensor or operation), it is added to the computational graph, which is an object that sits in the background and manages all the computations. Each placeholder has a default name, but you can also choose a name for it. In this example, I chose the name `place`.

Now, for advanced use cases, you might have more than one computational graphs, but there is always one which is the default one. To get the default one, I used `tf.get_default_graph()`. And then to get a reference to the placeholder, I used `get_tensor_by_name('place:0')`. (I used the name `'place:0'` instead of `'place'` because when you define a placeholder, in fact a `tf.Tensor` that you can feed is created, and also created is an operation which performs the feeding. The operation will have the name `'place'` whereas the actual tensor will have the name `'place:0'`.)

Comment: But, I have one problem if I run this code again jupyter notebook, I have this error:  ** InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'place_1' with dtype int32
  [[Node: place_1 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_INT32, shape=<unknown>, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]` **

Answer (score 1):

This is purely Python, but you can simply return the placeholder alongside the graph op created with it.

Like this:

```
return place*2, place
```

And then use f() like this:

```
y, place = f()
```

I think that it is a good idea to work within a class in Tensorflow, and have the ability to access these placeholders everywhere easily.

Edit: Of course, it is always possible to give your placeholder a name and then fetch it from the graph when you need to feed it.